# Ajax request - limited from current server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, limit

I have html page that has the following Js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url         :   "get.data.php",
        type        :   "POST",
        dataType    :   'json',
        data        :   {'data01': param01, 'data02': param02},
        success     :   function(data){
                //parsing the code
        }
    });
</script>
```

Well I'd like that the PHP get.data.php would detect where the request is coming from 
and answer correctly if it comes from a trusted server.. .or ignore the request if it is coming from a remote unknown server.

I have some ideas but I'd like to hear other's suggestions.

New Hint:
I want that only my web app on my webserver may access and retrive data from services PHP scripts such as get.data.php
And avoid that other webapp on other's webserver may address directly get.data.php to retrieve data, bypassing my webapp.

Comment: What you mean by trusted server? . Every users will be tracked?

Comment: AJAX requests come from browsers, not servers. Not sure quite what your use case is. Do you want to block some users?

Comment: @duke I want that only my web app on my webserver may access and retrive data from services PHP scripts such as get.data.php
And avoid that other webapp on other's webserver may address directly get.data.php to retrieve data, bypassing my webapp.

Comment: You can set some secret key/password to identify your requests and only that will be replied

Comment: @duke even if I set a key/password pair I will have to pass it by GET or POST.... anyone could see it and replicate the request... I don't see any improvement

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `$_SERVER` variable to get information about the request, then compare that information to your own data if its trusted or not

example:

```
$remote_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // get ip of the request
```

php-manual for [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: The advice you give is not going to work, since both the request containing the above script, and the request to get.data.php are coming from a different IP (from the webserverIP), even if get.data.php is subsequently called from the first page.

Comment: @kante is $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] set when you call from the javascript? though, that value is set by the browser

Comment: well using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] was my first idea... but it 's not always goin to work... there are some case in which Http_referer isn't set .. then no answer for anyone, even for the owner of the application